# Linked List removeNode C Programming

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

I was having some confusion between ListNode and LinkedList. Basically my question was divided into 2 parts. For first part, I was supposed to do with ListNode. The function prototype as such:

```
int removeNode(ListNode **ptrHead, int index);
```

All function were working fine for the ListNode part. Then as for the second part, I was supposed to change the function above to this:

```
int removeNode(LinkedList *11, int index);
```

My code for part 1 which is working fine look like this:

```
int removeNode(ListNode **ptrHead, int index) {
ListNode *pre, *cur;
if (index == -1)
    return 1;
else if (findNode(*ptrHead, index) != NULL) {
    pre = findNode(*ptrHead, index - 1);
    cur = pre->next;
    pre->next = cur->next;
    return 0;
}
else
    return 1;
}

ListNode *findNode(ListNode *head, int index) {
    ListNode *cur = head;
    if (head == NULL || index < 0)
        return NULL;
    while (index > 0) {
        cur = cur->next;
        if (cur == NULL) return NULL;
        index--;
    }
    return cur;
}
```

And here is my entire code for the part 2 which is not working:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _listnode {
    int num;
    struct _listnode *next;
}ListNode;

typedef struct _linkedlist {
    ListNode *head;
    int size;
}LinkedList;

void printNode2(ListNode *head);
int removeNode2(LinkedList *ll, int index);

int main()
{
    int value, index;
    ListNode *head = NULL, *newNode = NULL;
    LinkedList *ptr_ll = NULL;

    printf("Enter value, -1 to quit: ");
    scanf("%d", &value);
    while (value != -1) {
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            newNode = head;
        }
        else {
            newNode->next = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            newNode = newNode->next;
        }
        newNode->num = value;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        scanf("%d", &value);
    }

    printNode2(head);

    printf("\nEnter index to remove: ");
    scanf("%d", &index);
    removeNode2(ptr_ll, index);
    printNode2(head);

    return 0;
}

void printNode2(ListNode *head) {
    printf("Current list: ");
    while (head != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", head->num);
        head = head->next;
    }
}

int removeNode2(LinkedList *ll, int index) {
    ListNode *head = ll->head;
    if (head == index)
    {
        if (head->next == NULL)
        {
            printf("There is only one node. The list can't be made empty ");
            return 1;
        }

        /* Copy the data of next node to head */
        head->num = head->next->num;

        // store address of next node
        index = head->next;

        // Remove the link of next node
        head->next = head->next->next;

        return 0;
    }


    // When not first node, follow the normal deletion process

    // find the previous node
    ListNode *prev = head;
    while (prev->next != NULL && prev->next != index)
        prev = prev->next;

    // Check if node really exists in Linked List
    if (prev->next == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Given node is not present in Linked List");
        return 1;
    }

    // Remove node from Linked List
    prev->next = prev->next->next;

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run the part 2, the cmd just not responding and after a while, it just closed by itself and I have no idea which part went wrong. I was thinking am I in the correct track or the entire LinkedList part just wrong?

When I tried to run in debug mode, this error message popped up:

```
Exception thrown at 0x01201FD1 in tut.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not how software development works. Could you imagine if every time a program didn't work, the developer uploaded the entire program to stack overflow and asked "help"? You need to learn basic debugging skills immediately. Start with simple debug messages to let you know what's going on. If that doesn't work, it's time to fire up a debugger.

Comment: I pasted the entire code because I was having some confusion between ListNode and LinkedList. I was thinking if they are the same thing since the structure are quite the same. And from the notes, I was told that I have to create another C struct which is LinkedList so I was thinking if I am on the right track cause it seemed abit odd.

Comment: You might want to recompile the code with warnings enabled. There are a few mismatches between the nodes themselves and the list index you should look into. You also call `removeNode2` with `ptr_ll` when it is `NULL`. This is the first use of `ptr_ll`, so it can't possibly know about the previously inserted nodes. The whole point of the list structure is that you don't need a separate head, because the head is part of the list structure.

Comment: ListNode holds the actual data. In a real program, it would presumably hold more than just an integer. LinkedList is the root of the data structure.

Comment: @MOehm For example? Would you mind to point out the mistakes so that I can have a head start. I was thinking is it because I am storing the values into ListNode and passing a NULL LinkedList around and that caused the problem?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I see I see, so from my example, basically I am storing all the values into ListNode. I was thinking how should I pass all those value into LinkedList and pass the LinkedList pointer as parameter. I think the root of the problem above is because I am passing a NULL linked list pointer into removeNode2. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you got the linked list to work wihen the list is defined via the head pointer only. In this set-up, you have to pass a pointer to the head pointer when the list may be updated, and just the head pointer when you only inspect the list without modifying, for example:

```
int removeNode(ListNode **ptrHead, int index);
ListNode *findNode(ListNode *head, int index);
```

Here, the head pointer is the handle for the list that is visible to the client code.

The approach with the list struct defines a new interface for the linked list. While the head node is enough, it might be desirable to keep track of the tail as well for easy appending or of the number of nodes. This data can be bundles in the linked list struct.

What that means is that the handling of the nodes is left to the list and the client code uses only the linked list struct, for example:

```
typedef struct ListNode ListNode;
typedef struct LinkedList LinkedList;

struct ListNode {
    int num;
    ListNode *next;
};

struct LinkedList {
    ListNode *head;
    ListNode *tail;
    int size;
};

void ll_print(const LinkedList *ll);
void ll_prepend(LinkedList *ll, int num);
void ll_append(LinkedList *ll, int num);
void ll_remove_head(LinkedList *ll);

int main()
{
    LinkedList ll = {NULL};

    ll_append(&ll, 2);
    ll_append(&ll, 5);
    ll_append(&ll, 8);
    ll_print(&ll);

    ll_prepend(&ll, 1);
    ll_prepend(&ll, 0);
    ll_print(&ll);

    ll_remove_head(&ll);
    ll_print(&ll);

    while (ll.head) ll_remove_head(&ll);

    return 0;
}
```

There's also one difference: In the head-node set-up, the head node might be null. Here, the list cannot be null, it must exist. (Its head and tail members can be null, though.) Here the list is allocated on the stack, its address `&ll` must be passed to the functions.

In the linked list set-up, the distinction between modifying and read-only access is done via the `const` keyword:

```
void ll_print(const LinkedList *ll);
void ll_prepend(LinkedList *ll, int num);
```

In your example, you take a mixed approach with two independent structures, a head node and a list. That can't work, one single list is described by one struct, pick one.

The advantage to the linked list structure approach is that all required data like head, tail and size are always passed together to  a function. You can also hide the implementation from the user by not disclosing the struct members, so that theb user can only work on pointers to that struct.

Finally, here's an example implementation of the above interface for you to play with:

```
void ll_print(const LinkedList *ll)
{
    ListNode *node = ll->head;

    while (node != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", node->num);
        node = node->next;
    }

    putchar('\n');
}

void ll_prepend(LinkedList *ll, int num)
{
    ListNode *nnew = malloc(sizeof *nnew);

    nnew->next = ll->head;
    nnew->num = num;

    ll->head = nnew;
    if (ll->tail == NULL) ll->tail = ll->head;
    ll->size++;
}

void ll_append(LinkedList *ll, int num)
{
    ListNode *nnew = malloc(sizeof *nnew);

    nnew->next = NULL;
    nnew->num = num;

    if (ll->tail == NULL) {
        ll->tail = ll->head = nnew;
    } else {
        ll->tail->next = nnew;
        ll->tail = nnew;
    }
    ll->size++;
}

void ll_remove_head(LinkedList *ll)
{
    if (ll->head) {
        ListNode *ndel = ll->head;

        ll->head = ll->head->next;
        ll->size--;

        free(ndel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your explanations was good, really appreciated them, but I was not supposed to change the structure of the prototype because it's a beginner exercise. So I have modified my code based on your explanations into a simpler version, http://pastebin.com/Dr3P6QMp, it can run for now. However, when I try to remove the node based on the index position, it does not work, it's still printing the entire linked list. I was thinking where were the mistakes.

Comment: And the posted code works? You still have two independent structures: You add to nodes and try to delete from a list. That's like having a bakning account at Bank A and trying to withdraw money from bank B. You should also enable warnings: The pointers you pass to the removal function are incompatible. You must (1) create an object of struct list, not a null pointer and (2) pass it as pointer by taking its address. You just do (2).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92581/discussion-between-denise-and-m-oehm).